# How to print the percentage of disk use from `df -hl`

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I know that `df -hl` outputs a list of all my partitions with its size, usage as a percentage, and space available.

If I wanted to output just the size and usage as a percentage of `sda2` and `sda3`, for example, how could I tell Linux (Ubuntu) to check them, sum them and show them to me?

Comment: The answers below could be simplified by changing the df command they use to put the disks on the df command line instead of parsing through all of the disks. i.e. df -hl /dev/sda[23]

Answer (score 18):

For `df` to calculate totals, use the `--totals` option. If you want the totals only over some select drives, specify them as arguments.

### Examples (and output from my computer)

This is the total for all local mounts:

```
$ df --total -hl
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1              14G   12G  2,1G  85% /
none                  490M  660K  489M   1% /dev
none                  497M  1,5M  495M   1% /dev/shm
none                  497M  260K  496M   1% /var/run
none                  497M     0  497M   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda1             3,7G  418M  3,3G  12% /fastdisk
total                  19G   12G  7,3G  62%
```

Restricting to a few drives (note that if the specified path is not an exact mount point, the closest containing mount point is used **[see note at end]**):

```
$ df -hl --total /home /fastdisk
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1              14G   12G  2,1G  85% /
/dev/sda1             3,7G  418M  3,3G  12% /fastdisk
total                  17G   12G  5,3G  69%
```

or using `dev` names:

```
$ df -hl --total /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             3,7G  418M  3,3G  12% /fastdisk
/dev/sdb1              14G   12G  2,1G  85% /
total                  17G   12G  5,3G  69%
```

### Further customization

If you want to list all mounts except the ‘special’ ones, you can use the `-x` option to exclude by partition type. (Use the `-T` option to show the types.)

Personally, for interactive use, I use the following bash alias (added to `~/.bash_aliases`) to exclude the ‘non-physical’ mounts.

```bsh
alias df='df -h -x devtmpfs -x tmpfs -x debugfs'
```

### Note

Specifying paths within mount points can sometime yield results different form specifying the exact path to the mount point. For example, on my laptop I use `sshfs` to mount my (local) file-server.

```
df -h ~/.server-root/ ~/.server-root/disks/A ~/.server-root/disks/B
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
johan@server:/        185G   58G  118G  33% /home/johan/.server-root
johan@server:/        1,9T  637G  1,2T  35% /home/johan/.server-root
johan@server:/        1,8T  1,1T  757G  59% /home/johan/.server-root
```

The server root (`/`) is mounted at `~/.server-root`. However, on the server, disks are mounted on `/disks/*`, which `df` (on the laptop) does not ‘know’ about.

Evidently `df` can list the disk usage on the different mounts on the server, if given proper paths. However, it shows the same “Filesystem“ and “Mounted on“ for all the paths, since *(i believe)* that is the only mount point (relating to this `sshfs` mount) in the local kernel mount table.

---

**Another thing:** Not really related to the question, but related to a *previous answer* to the question.

Adding up the numbers with an `awk` script (or similar), like some previously posted answers do, is *not* a good idea when using the `-h` flag. This is because special handling is required. You can not just do `size+=$2;` for a field that is `418M` on one row and `12G` on another and get something useful out of it…

For an example with `awk`, adding `500M` to  `10.2G` yields

```
$ echo -e '500M\n10.2G' | awk '{size+=$1;} END{print size;}'
510.2
```

510.2 of what?

There is clearly a problem here. So, *just as a tip to remember*, when doing (automated) calculation on the output of `df` *(and others that can use **‘human readable’** numbers)*. Make sure that you do **not** use the `-h` flag and that the input to the calculation script is, instead, normalized (for example to bytes, blocks, KBs, or whatever) and do the *‘display scaling’* at the end. It is not to hard, in most scripting and programming languages, to add something like:

```
If value < threshold Then
  print (value),"B"
Else If value < 1024*threshold Then
  print (value/1024),"kB"
Else If value < 1024*1024*threshold Then
  print (value/1024/1024),"MB"
(and so on...)
```

where *value* is in bytes and *threshold* is a value on the order of 1000. The upshot of this method is that you can easily tune it to produce printed values (excluding the prefix) in a desired range and with a number of significant digits to your choosing. Compared to the case with standard utilities with `-h` switches, where the format is often fixed.

Of course, this calculation can often be made more efficient and/or elegant, but that is a question for the specific language it is written in. Frankly, if it is used in a *user script* that is run only now and then to interactively view some information, efficiency is not really a concern.

Answer (score 5):

I think you wanted the sum of both `size` and `use%`

```
 df -hl | grep 'sda2\|sda3' | awk 'BEGIN{print "Size","Use%"} {size+=$2;percent+=$5;} END{print size,percent}' | column -t
```

Comment: Ditto, the same as above.

Comment: @user32398: There are differences dude.

Comment: At the end of my answer to this question I elaborated a bit on why not to use a simplistic awk-approach (just `size+=$1`) to this question. This method is really not compatible with the `-h` option of `df`.

Answer (score 4):

You would use a tool like `awk`:

```
df -hl | awk '/^\/dev\/sd[ab]/ { sum+=$5 } END { print sum }'
```

Where:

- `/^\/dev\/sd[ab]/` is a pattern for filtering only those lines that begin with `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`
- `{ sum+=$5 }` add the fifth field for any matches of the above pattern

You can find some helpful `awk` references on the [Awk.info wiki](http://awk.info/?Learn).

Comment: I think it's not enought to sum the %, but thanks I get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo df -hl | grep 'mountdirname' | awk '{print $5}'
```

Comment: He asked for `size`, `% used`, and `available`.  Not just % used.  Also @mdpc has a better method for singling out the drive, but if you wanted to pattern match awk can do that:  `df -hl | awk '/sda2/{print $2,$5,$4}'`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted it with alerts, I do it with IFTTT, Telegram And WebHooks (Which is all free)

```
#!/bin/bash
diskusage=$(df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|mmcblk0p1' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }'| cut -f1 -d '%')
hostname=$(hostname)
tolerance=(85)
date=$(date)

if [[ "$diskusage" -gt "$tolerance" ]]
        then
        echo ""
        echo total disk usage is $diskusage%
        echo ""
        curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"--Alert--","value2":"Total disk usage is '$diskusage'% ","value3":"Host information: '$hostname' "}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{alert}/with/key/PutYourKeyHEre
fi
echo ''
echo Disk usage is $diskusage%. The tolerance is $tolerance%. No alert fired $date
echo Disk usage is $diskusage%. The tolerance is $tolerance%. No alert fired $date >> /var/log/IFTTT/checkdiskspace.log
```